# Pipe output of a command to an interactive python session?

Tags: python, redirect, pipe, interactive, ipython

What I'd like to do is something like

```
 $echo $PATH | python --remain-interactive "x = raw_input().split(':')"
 >>>
 >>> print x
 ['/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin']
```

I suppose ipython solution would be best. If this isn't achievable, what would be your solution for the situation where I want to process output from various other commands? I've used subprocess before to do it when I was desperate, but it is not ideal.

**UPDATE:** So this is getting closer to the end result:

```
 echo $PATH > /tmp/stdout.txt; ipython -i -c 'stdout = open("/tmp/stdout.txt").read()'
```

Now how can we go about bending this into a form

```
 echo $PATH | pyout
```

where `pyout` is the "magic solution to all my problems". It could be a shell script that writes the piped  output and then runs the ipython. Everything done fails for the same reasons bp says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IPython you can do this

```
x = !echo $$$$PATH
```

The double escape of `$` is a pain though

You could do this I guess

```
PATH="$PATH"
x = !echo $PATH
x[0].split(":")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--remain-interactive` switch you are looking for is `-i`. You also can use the `-c` switch to specify the command to execute, such as `__import__("sys").stdin.read().split(":")`. So what you would try is: (do not forget about escaping strings!)

```
echo $PATH | python -i -c x = __import__(\"sys\").stdin.read().split(\":\")
```

However, this is all that will be displayed:

```
>>>
```

So why doesn't it work? Because you are piping. The python intepreter is trying to interactively read commands from the same `sys.stdin` you are reading arguments from. Since `echo` is done executing, `sys.stdin` is closed and no further input can happen.

For the same reason, something like:

```
echo $PATH > spam
python -i -c x = __import__(\"sys\").stdin.read().split(\":\") < spam
```

...will fail.

What I would do is:

```
echo $PATH > spam.bar
python -i my_app.py spam.bar
```

After all, `open("spam.bar")` is a file object just like `sys.stdin` is :)

Comment: Obviously here I'm assuming you do know about `sys.path` and that `echo $PATH` was just some random command you used to illustrate your point.

Comment: @bp, sys.path is the path python uses to import modules. It's not the same as $PATH. You are probably thinking of `os.environ["PATH"]`

Comment: @bp, a nod to your comment. About your answer, I don't want to have to write a my_app to parse the output. Putting, for example, the .split(':') in its own file would be annoying. That -i switch will be handy in its own right; I thought I misunderstood it because it wasn't working (much like your first example shows).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Python axiom of "There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it" I'm reasonably sure that there won't be a better way to interact with other processes than [the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

It might help if you could say why something like the following "is not ideal":

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'echo %PATH%'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print process.communicate()[0].split(';')
```

(In your specific example you could use [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-parameters) but I realise that's not really what you're asking.)

Comment: So if I was at the shell command line and wanted to quickly and easily get some output into a working interpreter, do you think this is ideal? Simply put, it doesn't redirect the shell's stdout to a new interactive session. It isn't ideal because it starts the session first and then runs the shell command. I may be able to get a bash function to write a temp file with this and have ipython run it.